# Setting up multi network using Docker Compose (for frontend & backend environments)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

hi everyone i'm kinda new to Docker - I am looking to migrate from Vagrant (using Scotchbox 1.x) - our current setup consists of a PHP/Apache/MySQL backend & an Angular frontend - I run a vagrant instance for each of these with the IP addresses 192.168.33.10 & 192.168.33.11 mapped to my.frontend.local & my.backend.local respectively in my hosts file.
Can anyone suggest the best ways to achieve with Docker?

I have got this far currently but unsure how to do this using Docker Compose
https://docs.docker.com/compose/

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  php:
    build: './php/'
    networks:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - ./backend_public_html/:/var/www/html/
  apache:
    build: './apache/'
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
  networks:
    - frontend
    - backend
   ports:
     - "8080:80"
   volumes:
     - ./public_html/:/var/www/html/
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.6.40
networks:
  - backend
environment:
  - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpassword
networks:
  frontend:
  backend:
```

Comment: Yaml files are whitespace sensitive. The indentation in the code above is incorrect in quite a few places. Does this match the file you are actually trying to run, or just an error in copy/pasting to SO?

Comment: sorry - the whitespace is just for the copy/paste into stackoverflow it does not match the file itself